# To handle rational number without losing accuracy of computation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, computation

I want to use this rational number in computations without losing the accuracy of the picture in Matlab:

```
f = 359.0 + 16241/16250.0
```

I think storing, for instance by `f = uint64(359.0 + 16241/16250.0)` loses accuracy, seen as 360 in Matlab.

I think the best way to handle the thing is never to store the value but to store its factors like

```
% f = a + b/c
a = 359
b = 16241
c = 16250
```

and then doing computation by the variables a, b and c, and giving the result as a picture.

**Is this a good way to maintain the accuracy?**

Comment: What kind of computation do you want to do with this number? What do you mean by "picture"?

Comment: Same question as A. Donda, please clarify.

Comment: Actually, Matlab "sees" this number as about `359.99944615384617918`. If you compute `x = 359 + 16241/16250` and then `(x - 359) * 16250`, this results in `16241.000000000411092`, i.e. the absolute error of `x` is about 2.5e-14. Do you really need better precision than this?

Comment: @A.Donda I am doing time-frequency analysis with quadratic distributions where I need exact computation to be able to control the cross term and interference.

Comment: @A.Donda So Matlab stores this value as floating point value in your example. Right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: Not sure whether I understand the specific requirements of your application, but usually double precision is enough for time–frequency analysis. If it is on empirical data, their imprecision is usually much higher, if only because of limited A/D conversion. If this doesn't make sense to you, I think it would help if you could expand your question with more details and background, and possibly code.

Comment: Yes, "double" is a 64-bit floating point number, with about 16 decimal digits precision. And effectively, for your number you have about 14 decimal digits precision.

Comment: @A.Donda You are right when we have empirical data. It seems that C provides better accuracy here. Right?

Comment: I have to verify how much the error is in databases which follow AAMI standards for A/D conversion. You think it is bigger there than Matlab error?

Comment: Not an expert on C, but as far as I remember the C data types are not universally defined, but their precision depends on the machine architecture and/or compiler. By contrast, a Matlab "double" is always the same, regardless of machine or Matlab version. Since 64 bit architecture is the norm these days, I'd expect a C "double" to be the same as a Matlab "double". There seems to be a "long double" though, which might provide better accuracy, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types

Comment: I sometimes work with EEG data, and there 12 bit precision *fixed point* is the norm, with special amplifiers maybe reaching 16 bits. That's so much less than the 52 bits *floating point* of a "double" that those differences don't really matter.

Comment: @A.Donda What can you say about the behaviour of this error in Matlab? Is it linear or harmonic?

Comment: Standard CD audio is 16 bits fixed point, production quality audio 24 or maybe 32 bits. So you see, nothing to worry. – For floating point the error is relative, I guess that's what you would call "harmonic".

Comment: @A.Donda I had in mind Wigner-Ville distribution's cross term here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_distribution_function#Cross_term_property I thought how the size of the error of computation behaves in Matlab.

Comment: It's been a long time, but I once computed the Wigner–Ville distribution in Matlab, and I don't remember any numerical difficulties. I'd recommend the following: a) check the precision of your input data, b) artificially introduce small errors in your data and see whether it relevantly affects the results.

Comment: @A.Donda Is it enough to add element-wise epsilon = 0.0001 for instance to the time-frequency representation matrix B?

Comment: I would go for a randomized relative error, e.g. `B = B + 0.0001 * mean(abs(B(:))) * randn(size(B));`. The factor might be smaller, since the expected numerical relative error is of the order of 1e-16. Also, I'd modify the input data you compute the time–frequency representatin from, not the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you suggest, if you absolutely don't want to lose accuracy when storing a rational number, the best solution probably is to store the number in terms of its integer components.

Instead of your three components (`f = a + b/c`) you can reduce the reprentation to two components: `f = n/d`. Thus each rational number would be defined (and stored) as the two-component integer vector `[n d]`. For example, the number `f` in your example corresponds to `n=5849991` and `d=16250`.

To simplify handling rational numbers stored this way, you could define a helper function which converts from the `[n d]` representation to `n/d` before applyling the desired operation:

```
useInteger = @(x, nd, fun) fun(x,double(nd(1))/double(nd(2)));
```

Then

```
>> x = sqrt(pi);
>> nd = int64([5849991 16250]);
>> useInteger(x, nd, @plus)
ans =
  361.7719
>> useInteger(x, nd, @times)
ans =
  638.0824
```

If you want to achieve arbitrarily high precision in computations, you should consider using [variable-precision arithmetic (`vpa`)](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/vpa.html) with string arguments. With that approach you get to specify how many digits you want:

```
>> vpa('sqrt(pi)*5849991/16250', 50)
ans =
638.08240465923757600307902117159072301901656248436
```

Comment: What do you estimate is the absolute error of this method? Better than 2.5e-14?

Comment: For _storing_: the error is zero, because you store the exact numerator and denominator in integer form. For _computing_: the error is the same as if you did `x*5849991/16250` directly

Comment: Please, see my answer as an extension to your answer. I got more error from computation than storing. Computation error, I think, should be the same in both cases, nevertheless you store variable or not.

Comment: @Masi I'm not sure I understand your answer. Anyway, if you want arbitrarily high precision, consider using `vpa`. See my updated answer and its link

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps create a `Rational` class and define the needed operations (`plus`,`minus`,`times`,etc.).  Start with something like this:

**Rational.m**

```
classdef Rational
    properties
        n;
        d;
    end
    methods
        function obj = Rational(n,d)
            GCD = gcd(n,d);
            obj.n = n./GCD;
            obj.d = d./GCD;
        end

        function d = dec(obj)
            d = double(obj.n)/double(obj.d);
        end

        % X .* Y
        function R = times(X,Y)
            chkxy(X,Y);
            if isnumeric(X),
                N = X .* Y.n; D = Y.d;
            elseif isnumeric(Y),
                N = X.n .* Y; D = X.d;
            else
                N = X.n .* Y.n; D = X.d .* Y.d;
            end
            R = Rational(N,D);
        end

        % X * Y
        function R = mtimes(X,Y)
            R = times(X,Y);
        end

        % X ./ Y
        function R = rdivide(X,Y)
            if isnumeric(Y),
                y = Rational(1,Y);
            else
                y = Rational(Y.d,Y.n);
            end
            R = times(X,y);
        end

        % X / Y
        function R = mrdivide(X,Y)
            R = rdivide(X,Y);
        end

        % X + Y
        function R = plus(X,Y)
            chkxy(X,Y);
            if isnumeric(X),
                N = X.*Y.d + Y.n; D = Y.d;
            elseif isnumeric(Y),
                N = Y.*X.d + X.n; D = X.d;
            else
                D = lcm(X.d,Y.d);
                N = sum([X.n Y.n].*(D./[X.d Y.d]));
            end
            R = Rational(N,D);
        end

        % X - Y
        function R = minus(X,Y)
            R = plus(X,-Y);
        end

        % -X
        function R = uminus(X)
            R = Rational(-X.n,X.d);
        end

        function chkxy(X,Y)
            if (~isa(X, 'Rational') && ~isnumeric(X)) || ...
                    (~isa(Y, 'Rational') && ~isnumeric(Y)),
                error('X and Y must be Rational or numeric.');
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**Examples**

Construct objects:

```
>> clear all % reset class definition
>> r1 = Rational(int64(1),int64(2))
r1 = 
  Rational with properties:

    n: 1
    d: 2
>> r2 = Rational(int64(3),int64(4))
r2 = 
  Rational with properties:

    n: 3
    d: 4
```

Add and subtract:

```
>> r1+r2
ans = 
  Rational with properties:

    n: 5
    d: 4
>> r1-r2
ans = 
  Rational with properties:

    n: -1
    d: 4
```

Multiply and divide:

```
>> r1*r2
ans = 
  Rational with properties:

    n: 3
    d: 8
>> r1/r2
ans = 
  Rational with properties:

    n: 2
    d: 3
```

Get decimal value:

```
>> r12 = r1/r2; % 2/3 ((1/2)/(3/4))
>> f = r12.dec
f =
    0.6667
```

Comment: Should *int64* be *uint64*?

Comment: It could be, but a signed data type is necessary for subtraction to work right. `int64` is plenty of bits. In fact, `double` gives you 53 bits of exact integer representation, so that would be good enough in just about every case.

Comment: I added an extension below to your answer below. I have Wigner-Ville distribution which gives me double. I want to multiply double with Rational. Can you give an example to do this?

Comment: @Masi Create `Rational` with `double` numerator/denominator. Again, 53-bits for exact integers up to 9,007,199,254,740,992.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to LuisMendo's answer

I got this as the error for your suggestion by py

```
>>> a = 638.08240465923757600307902117159072301901656248436059
>>> a
638.0824046592376             % do not know if Python is computing here with exact number
>>> b = 638.0824
>>> ave = abs(b+a)/2
>>> diff = abs(b-a)
>>> ave = abs(b+a)/2
>>> diff/ave
7.30193709165014e-09
```

which is more than the proposed error storing error above.

I run in WolframAlpha

```
x = sqrt(pi)
x*5849991/16250
```

and get

```
509.11609919757198016211937362635174599076143654820109
```

I am not sure if this is what you meant in your comment of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to chappjc's answer.

I have now

```
[B,T,F] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1)); % here F double
fs = Rational(uint64(5849991), uint64(16250));
t = 1/fs;
imagesc(T*t, F*fs, B);
```

I run it

```
Error using  .* 
Integers can only be combined with integers of
the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in  .*  (line 23)
                    N = X .* Y.n; D = Y.d;

Error in  *  (line 34)
                R = times(X,Y);
```

**How can you multiply in this class the double with Rational?**

Comment: `T` and `F` are vectors (not scalars), so the `Rational` needs to be generated with `double` numerator/denominator. But I don't see what this approach gains you.  Why keep a rational representation if you are multiplying by decimal values (i.e. `T` and `F`)?

Comment: For `imagesc` you'd have to do `F*fs.dec`, but that is not any better than doing `F*5849991/16250`. Using a rational class like `Rational` only helps if you are doing arithmetic on multiple rational numbers.

Comment: @chappjc Yes, I am developing the Wigner-Ville distribution in Rational numbers. For these examples, I have to refer to the available public resources to communicate.