# Exact fraction arithmetic without Matlab converting to decimal representation?

Tags: matlab

So suppose I want to compute `1/9+1/13` in exact fraction form. Since both numbers are rational, an exact result in fraction form is possible. But when I type `1/9+1/13` in Matlab, the result is always a decimal approximation.

How do I obtain exact fractional form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To handle rational number without losing accuracy of computation in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870085/to-handle-rational-number-without-losing-accuracy-of-computation-in-matlab)

Comment: My personal favourite solution is to implement a 'Rational' class as one of the answer in the duplicate question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab is primarily a numeric environment and thus uses [floating-point numbers by default](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html). Generally, you'll need to use the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) for something like what you describe. In the case of your example:

```
sym('1/9')+sym('1/13')
```

returns `22/117`.

Alternatively, you could try the [`rats`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rats.html) (rational fraction approximation) function that works with floating point inputs:

```
rats(1/9+1/13)
```

returns the string `'22/117'`. There's also [`rat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rat.html) that returns the numerator and denominator as separate floating point outputs.

```
[n,d] = rat(1/9+1/13)
```

returns `22` and `117` for `n` and `d`, respectively.